# why is it okay to use "is" in front of "interested"

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Is it grammatically right to say: "If he **is interested** in the project, he will ask you many questions"

It sounds alright to me and I noticed this uses future simple tense, however, I'm curious to know why it is acceptable to use the word **is** before the past tense word **interested**

Comment: Check out that link. It has your answer. The short version is, [quoting StoneyB](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301261/why-do-some-words-in-the-simple-present-end-in-ed#comment679079_301261): *Those are not past-tense verbforms but past participles which have achieved an existence as adjectives independent of their verbal origins*.

Comment: "Interested" is not a verb here, but an adjective. It functions as head of the AdjP "interested in the project". That it's an adjective is evident from the fact that it can be modified by "very", which the verb "interested" can't.

Answer (score 2):

Past participles (such as "interested") can also be used as adjectives, preceded by the appropriate part of the verb "be".

[Participial adjectives](https://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/490/grammar/participial-adjectives.htm)